Is there a way to detect mouse presses in python that can work inline without needing to use a listener?
I have a program where I am trying to send the status of the mouse over the internet to another computer, so that the second computer can mimic the inputs of the first computer. I am having trouble trying to actually detect the mouse presses from the computer. Specifically, I need some form of command that will return a value such as 0 or 1 depending on whether the mouse is pressed down at the instant that the line is ran, that then immediately proceeds to the next chunk of the code afterwards.
I have tried using pynput to detect mouse inputs, but it interrupts the entirety of program flow, and waits until an event happens, which is the opposite of what I want to happen. I have also tried to use pywin32 but it doesn't appear that the module actually works, despite trying to import it in several ways, such as with "import pywin32" or "import win32api".
My code is as follows:
import socket
import pyautogui
import time
from pynput.mouse import Listener

mouseDown = 0

def is_clicked(x, y, button, pressed):
    if pressed:
        mouseDown = 1
        return False
    else:
        mouseDown = 0
        return False

client = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)

server_host = 'server name'

client.connect((server_host, 12000))

while True:
    pos = pyautogui.position()
    posx = pos[0]
    posy = pos[1]
    client.send(posx.to_bytes(2, 'big'))
    client.send(posy.to_bytes(2, 'big'))
    is_clicked()
    one = 1
    zero = 0
    if mouseDown == 1:
        client.send(one.to_bytes(1, 'big'))
    else:
        client.send(zero.to_bytes(1, 'big'))
    print(str(pos))
    #image_data = file.read(2048)
    time.sleep(1/60)


    file.close()
    client.close()`


You just missed to make mouseDown global.
